# Separate MySQL Docker Container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to find out if I can make a separate Docker container for MySQL with the following conditions:

1. Use docker-compose for the build
2. Use host's OS
3. Use host's MySQL folder for saving data

I've done numbers #1 and #2 successfully using only a Docker file but not with docker-compose and I'm trying to cut down the learning curve by studying a working example. With regards to #3 I'm not really sure if it's possible. I'm thinking of a symbolic link but not really sure.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/)?

Comment: Yes. I get your drift but can you explain further?

Comment: Mount the host's mysql folder as a volume using the `-v` argument to `docker run` (or the equivalent configuration in `docker-compose`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already done with #1 and #2 and regarding #3 point , yes you can mount the host volume to container volume and it can be run through the docker-compose.

docker compose is tool which used for running multiple container and configuring the those containers.Docker compose uses .yml file for configuration.

You need to first create docker image from dockerfile then install docker-compose

https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose

Then create .yml file and define the mysql configuration like below for example.

```
 mysqldb:
        image: mysql
        container_name: ${MYSQL_HOST}
        restart: always
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
- "./data/db/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/

Answer (score 0):

You can and should run MySQL in a separate container. You can create this as a separate docker image, or run the two separate containers from the same docker image. The containers can be started from either docker-compose or bash.

In early releases of docker (v1.0), my experience with docker volumes was not positive. Still today, I mount the host OS for persistent data storage with **-v**, and this has worked well for me. The **-v** option allows the use of the **host OS** data folder.